# Tool for processing large CSV files

Tags: csv, bigdata

I have a large CSV file of over 8 million rows. I need to process the timestamps in the data and perform aggregate operations like sum/average by grouping on various values of an attribute.

I imported the data into Oracle using SQL*Loader, but query execution and exporting the result set is taking too much time. As an example, I need to compute the total and average time spent on events of a particular kind grouped by a user identifier. This involves queries like `sum(max(timestamp)-min(timestamp)) where event='eventType' group by ID`.

Running this query for all types of events and exporting the result set as a csv using TOAD won't complete in tractable time.

Any alternatives?

Comment: LogParser? : https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=24659

Comment: [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org) is a possibility.  UC Berkeley has a [MOOC](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-big-data-apache-spark-uc-berkeleyx-cs100-1x) on it and the hand-on labs are semi structured text/csv analyses like word counting and web log files and matching up product descriptions .

Comment: How much time is too much time?  This is surprising.  I would think any modern RDBMS would handle this like a champ.  Is Oracle running on a server or locally?